# java web start blocked application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-web-start

I wrote a javaFx app and i want to run it through network so i use java web start
but when i launch my jnlp file i've got this error :

[image]

BTW, i was google this problem and one solution was add url to the exception list so i don't want all users to modify their java security ,
Is there any other way ?

So, i've used IntelliJ for creating jnlp and test both self signed and signed by key

[image]

Comment: Why would it say "file:" when you say you want to run it over network? Also, have you signed your jar with a certificate that's trusted by java or added the signer certificate to the trusted ones?

Comment: how and where can i find and add trusted certificate ?

Comment: If you sign your jar, you have your signer certificate that you trust. If you don't sign the jar, then you must get one or generate one yourself. Search for self-signed jar or so.

Comment: *"self signed"* As easily as you can make a digital certificate saying it is you, I can fake a digital certificate that claims it's you. That's why Oracle ended up deciding it was not going to treat a self signed certificate seriously. Use a proper certificate from a CA.